# Raphael: Chaining ".data" to a raphael.js element

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm having trouble **chaining "[.data](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data)"** to a raphael.js element.

When I try to retrieve the data later, I get "**undefined**".

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HkNgT/9/

```
//Draw:
paper.circle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleCenterRadius)
    .attr({'fill':'blue', 'stroke':'red', 'stroke-width':2, 'opacity': 0.8}) 
    .data({"circleCenterX":circleCenterX, 
           "circleCenterY":circleCenterY, 
           "boxYPosition":boxYPosition, 
           "boxXPosition":boxXPosition})
    .id = name+"-circle";

//Output:
    console.log("data is = ", paper.getById(name+"-circle").data("circleCenterX"));
```

With this code, the "**.data(...)**" **part** just **doesn't work**.

When I try to retrieve it (with paper.getById), it displays "**data is = undefined**".

Other ways that I have tried:

```
    //Doesn't work
    paper.circle....
    .data("circleCenterX",circleCenterX)
    .data("circleCenterY",circleCenterY)
    .data("boxYPosition",boxYPosition)
    .data("boxXPosition",boxXPosition);
```

And another:

```
    //Doesn't work
    var c = paper.circle....;
    c.data("circleCenterX",circleCenterX);
    c.data("circleCenterY",circleCenterY);
    c.data("boxYPosition",boxYPosition);
    c.data("boxXPosition",boxXPosition);
```

And another:

```
    //DOES work, but gives me huge performance losses
    paper.circle....;
    paper.getById(name+"-circle").data("circleCenterX",circleCenterX);
    paper.getById(name+"-circle").data("circleCenterY",circleCenterY);
    paper.getById(name+"-circle").data("boxYPosition",boxYPosition);
    paper.getById(name+"-circle").data("boxXPosition",boxXPosition);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just trying to help, I've never used raphael before. I assume you're trying to retrieve the `circleCenterX` value?

Inspecting the `data` function, it looks as though it's only used for setting the value. (It only returns a value, if you're setting a value).

```
function (b,c){
    var d = bb[this.id] = bb[this.id] || {};
    if(arguments.length==1){
        if(a.is(b,"object")){
            for(var e in b)b[g](e)&&this.data(e,b[e]);
            return this
        }
        eve("raphael.data.get."+this.id,this,d[b],b);
        return d[b]
    }
    d[b]=c,eve("raphael.data.set."+this.id,this,c,b);
    return this
}
```

(Afaict, `eve` is an Event framework, bundled with `Raphael`. Anyone know where the data goes from here?)

So this isn't going to help.

Inspecting the circle object, I was able to see/pull out a `cx` value, which I assume is the `circleCenterX` value that you're looking for...

```
var circ = paper.getById(name+"-circle");
console.log("baseVal is = ", circ[0].cx.baseVal.value);
console.log("animVal is = ", circ[0].cx.animVal.value);
```

Gives

```
baseVal is =  100
animVal is =  100
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey, this works! Although not what I was expecting, the answer works great! Thanks a lot ^-^